# How can I exceed the daily bank limit with an online purchase?

Tags: payment, online

I need to pay online a one time amount which exceeds my daily limit. Card is Indian and debit, I can't go for EMI options. Any solution?

Answer (score 3):

You could talk to your bank and ask them to increase your daily limit.

Another option is to talk to the vendor that you are trying to pay, and see if they will let you pay part of the total each day for a few days.